# Will there be a grace period for the CA change to mandatory 1 year?

Tags: certificates, web-browser, certificate-authority

As I can see some sites were working yesterday and today they are not working so my guess is browsers have a grace period set in them. [certificate lifespans limited to 1 year in browsers](https://www.zdnet.com/article/apple-strong-arms-entire-ca-industry-into-one-year-certificate-lifespans/).

Maybe this is based on the Certificate Authority.
[TLS 39 month certificate limit and Chrome's NET::ERR_CERT_VALIDITY_TOO_LONG error](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/85590/tls-39-month-certificate-limit-and-chromes-neterr-cert-validity-too-long-erro))

[image: Expired certificate]

Where is the best place to check for this? Will the canary build handle this check for me so we can see the failure early on? What is the best way to handle spread out certificates in a centralised location?

Comment: Note that LetsEncrypt limits to 90 days, and always has, by their own decision. And the example you posted expired June 2, so it wasn't working July 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a grace period build in. To cite from [digicert](https://www.digicert.com/position-on-1-year-certificates/):

> ... Apple announced that beginning Sept. 1, **newly issued** publicly trusted TLS certificates are valid for no longer than 398 days.

Thus, this is only about certificates issued after Sept. 1. and it does not affect already issued certificates. This also means that there is nothing to worry about when hosting a site, since already issued certificates are not affected. Note that there was already a limit in place how long certificates issued by public CA should be valid, this limit is now only made shorter.